shadcn/radix navigation menu center and prevent overflow
I'm using shadcn library and their navigation menu component (https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/navigation-menu). I want to center the content around the trigger. Here is my tweaked code that actually works but when the content is too wide, it is still centered and hence overflow the browser window. How to automaticaly detect whether it overflow browser and somehow move it to the right?
import * as React from 'react';
import * as NavigationMenuPrimitive from '@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu';
import { cva } from 'class-variance-authority';
import { ChevronDown } from 'lucide-react';

import { cn } from '@/lib/utils';

const NavigationMenu = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Root>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Root>
>(({ className, children, ...props }, ref) => (
  <NavigationMenuPrimitive.Root
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      'relative z-10 flex max-w-max flex-1 items-center justify-center',
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  >
    {children}
    <NavigationMenuViewport />
  </NavigationMenuPrimitive.Root>
));
NavigationMenu.displayName = NavigationMenuPrimitive.Root.displayName;

const NavigationMenuList = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.List>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.List>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <NavigationMenuPrimitive.List
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      'group flex flex-1 list-none items-center justify-center space-x-1',
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  />
));
NavigationMenuList.displayName = NavigationMenuPrimitive.List.displayName;

const NavigationMenuItem = NavigationMenuPrimitive.Item;

const navigationMenuTriggerStyle = cva(
  'group inline-flex h-10 w-max items-center justify-center rounded-md bg-header px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium transition-colors hover:bg-accent hover:text-accent-foreground focus:bg-accent focus:text-accent-foreground focus:outline-none disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:opacity-50 data-[active]:bg-accent/50 data-[state=open]:bg-accent/50'
);

const NavigationMenuTrigger = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Trigger>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Trigger>
>(({ className, children, ...props }, ref) => (
  <NavigationMenuPrimitive.Trigger
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(navigationMenuTriggerStyle(), 'group', className)}
    {...props}
  >
    {children}{' '}
    <ChevronDown
      className='relative top-[1px] ml-1 h-3 w-3 transition duration-200 group-data-[state=open]:rotate-180'
      aria-hidden='true'
    />
  </NavigationMenuPrimitive.Trigger>
));
NavigationMenuTrigger.displayName = NavigationMenuPrimitive.Trigger.displayName;

const NavigationMenuContent = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Content>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Content>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <NavigationMenuPrimitive.Content
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      'left-0 top-0 w-full data-[motion^=from-]:animate-in data-[motion^=to-]:animate-out data-[motion^=from-]:fade-in data-[motion^=to-]:fade-out data-[motion=from-end]:slide-in-from-right-52 data-[motion=from-start]:slide-in-from-left-52 data-[motion=to-end]:slide-out-to-right-52 data-[motion=to-start]:slide-out-to-left-52 md:absolute md:w-auto ',
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  />
));
NavigationMenuContent.displayName = NavigationMenuPrimitive.Content.displayName;

const NavigationMenuLink = NavigationMenuPrimitive.Link;

const NavigationMenuViewport = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <div className={cn('absolute top-full flex justify-center')}>
    <NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport
      className={cn(
        'filter-card box-shadow-card origin-top-center relative mt-1.5 h-[var(--radix-navigation-menu-viewport-height)] w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md border border bg-popover text-popover-foreground shadow-lg data-[state=open]:animate-in data-[state=closed]:animate-out data-[state=closed]:zoom-out-95 data-[state=open]:zoom-in-90 md:w-[var(--radix-navigation-menu-viewport-width)]',
        className
      )}
      ref={ref}
      forceMount
      {...props}
    />
  </div>
));
NavigationMenuViewport.displayName =
  NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport.displayName;

const NavigationMenuIndicator = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Indicator>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Indicator>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <NavigationMenuPrimitive.Indicator
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      'top-full z-[1] flex h-1.5 items-end justify-center overflow-hidden data-[state=visible]:animate-in data-[state=hidden]:animate-out data-[state=hidden]:fade-out data-[state=visible]:fade-in',
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  >
    <div className='relative top-[60%] h-2 w-2 rotate-45 rounded-tl-sm bg-border shadow-md' />
  </NavigationMenuPrimitive.Indicator>
));
NavigationMenuIndicator.displayName =
  NavigationMenuPrimitive.Indicator.displayName;

export {
  navigationMenuTriggerStyle,
  NavigationMenu,
  NavigationMenuList,
  NavigationMenuItem,
  NavigationMenuContent,
  NavigationMenuTrigger,
  NavigationMenuLink,
  NavigationMenuIndicator,
  NavigationMenuViewport,
};



I ran into a similar problem and figured it out. In my problem, the navigationmenu was causing scrollbars to occur when the navigationmenu opened and it was on the right side of the screen. To fix this, I adjusted the shadcn NavigationMenuViewport component to the following (marked with //This is where you make adjustment):
Original Shadcn NavigationMenuViewport
const NavigationMenuViewport = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <div className={cn("absolute left-0 top-full flex justify-center")}> //This is where you make the adjustment. I show how I changed it below
    <NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport
      className={cn(
        "origin-top-center relative mt-1.5 h-[var(--radix-navigation-menu-viewport-height)] w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md border bg-popover text-popover-foreground shadow data-[state=open]:animate-in data-[state=closed]:animate-out data-[state=closed]:zoom-out-95 data-[state=open]:zoom-in-90 md:w-[var(--radix-navigation-menu-viewport-width)]",
        className
      )}
      ref={ref}
      {...props}
    />
  </div>
))
NavigationMenuViewport.displayName =
  NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport.displayName

Adjusted Shadcn NavigationMenuViewport
const NavigationMenuViewport = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <div className={cn("absolute left-auto right-0 top-full flex justify-center")}> //This is where you make the adjustment
    <NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport
      className={cn(
        "origin-top-center relative mt-1.5 h-[var(--radix-navigation-menu-viewport-height)] w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md border bg-popover text-popover-foreground shadow data-[state=open]:animate-in data-[state=closed]:animate-out data-[state=closed]:zoom-out-95 data-[state=open]:zoom-in-90 md:w-[var(--radix-navigation-menu-viewport-width)]",
        className
      )}
      ref={ref}
      {...props}
    />
  </div>
))
NavigationMenuViewport.displayName =
  NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport.displayName

This change ensured my navigationmenu dropdown wouldn't cause an overflow if it was close to the right side of the window.
Based on your last question of:

How to automaticaly detect whether it overflow browser and somehow
move it to the right?

I am assuming that your navigationmenu is on the left side of the screen already and it's overflowing to the left?
If that's the case your NavigationMenuViewport would look something like this:
const NavigationMenuViewport = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <div className={cn("absolute right-auto left-0 top-full flex justify-center")}> // This is where the change is made.
    <NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport
      className={cn(
        "origin-top-center relative mt-1.5 h-[var(--radix-navigation-menu-viewport-height)] w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md border bg-popover text-popover-foreground shadow data-[state=open]:animate-in data-[state=closed]:animate-out data-[state=closed]:zoom-out-95 data-[state=open]:zoom-in-90 md:w-[var(--radix-navigation-menu-viewport-width)]",
        className
      )}
      ref={ref}
      {...props}
    />
  </div>
))
NavigationMenuViewport.displayName =
  NavigationMenuPrimitive.Viewport.displayName

Either way, the two changed examples above should fix overflow issues on either the left or right side dependent on what your specific issue is.
